# Call an outer method for each public method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods

Let's have these two classes:

```
class Outer {
    public function mySpecialMethod($method_name_string) {
        // do something very complex
    }
}

class lotsOfMethods {
    public function a() {
        // do something
    }

    public function b() {
        // do something
    }

    public function c() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I want `a()`, `b()` and `c()` to call `mySpecialMethod($method_name_string)` automatically when these little methods get called **without manually calling it for each method**. It should also be receiving the method name as an argument.

This concept is very abstract to my eyes and I am unsure if something like this is even doable in PHP. If there is, I'd appreciate an answer a lot.

Comment: In general: no, it's not possible. Specifically you may be able to do something with `__call` or with certain wrapper design patterns, but overall it's not exactly clear what the goal is here and why this is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: OOP you say? Is that the 'Poltergeist-' or the 'Walking through a Minefield'-Anti-Pattern you're trying to code here?

Comment: I am totally confident of what I'm doing here. I just need a solution for my problem and I'd appreciate an answer.

Comment: @deceze I read a bit about `__call`, but I don't know how to make use of it in this case. Any help is very welcome

Comment: I can only guess what exactly it is you want to do, but if you want to implicitly call code without explicitly writing the call, you may be looking for something like Aspect Oriented Programming: http://go.aopphp.com/docs/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example of how to use:

```
<?php

class Outer
{
    public function mySpecialMethod($method_name_string)
    {
        $a = new lotsOfMethods();
        $a->{$method_name_string}();
    }
}

class lotsOfMethods
{
    public function a()
    {
        echo 'a';
    }

    public function b()
    {
        echo 'b';
    }

    public function c()
    {
        echo 'c';
    }
}


$outer = new Outer();

$outer->mySpecialMethod("a");
$outer->mySpecialMethod("b");
$outer->mySpecialMethod("c");
```

Comment: I agree this is better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can imagine is giving the function as a paremeter in a function like

```
public function runFunction($method) {
    // always call the mySpecialMethod(method)
    // also add the method as parameter to myspecialmethod
    mySpecialMethod($method);

    //check what to do based on parameter
    switch ($method) {
    case "a":
       a();
      break;
    case "b":
      b();
      break;
    case "c":
      c();
      break;
  }
}


public function a() {
    // do something
}

public function b() {
    // do something
}

public function c() {
    // do something
}
```

If you create a new function you should add the new function to the switch, so I would not recomment it, I rather would add the mySpecialMethod() in the new functions. The only benefit is you can always decide to run the functions directly like a() without the mySpecialMethod.